# How do I get the raw pre-deserialized value of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an encrypted type in my model

```
attribute :name, :encrypted
```

Which is

```
class EncryptedType < ActiveRecord::Type::Text
```

And implements `#serialize`, `#deserialize`, and `#changed_in_place?`.

How can I get the raw value from the database before deserialization?

I want to create a rake task to encrypt values which are in the DB that existed before the fields were encrypted. So before the encryption, the `name` field contained `Bob`. After the code change with encryption, reading that value will produce an error (caught), returning an empty string. I want to read the raw value and set it like a normal attribute so it will encrypt it. After the encryption, the field will look like `UD8yDrrXYEJXWrZGUGCCQpIAUCjoXCyKOsplsccnkNc=`.

I want something like `user.name_raw` or `user.raw_attributes[:name]`.

Comment: What about defining a method called `unencrypted` that process the `encrypted` attribute? So you can refer to this method instead of the original attribute. This looks more cohesive, once the `encrypt` name means the data will be encrypted.

Comment: This is also pretty useful when printing attributes with YAML. `y(instance.attributes_before_type_cast)` is way better readable than `y(instance.attributes)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::BeforeTypeCast](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html) which

> provides a way to read the value of the attributes before typecasting and deserialization

and has `read_attribute_before_type_cast` and `attributes_before_type_cast`. Additionally,

> it declares a method for all attributes with the *_before_type_cast suffix

So for instance:

```
User.last.created_at_before_type_cast # => "2017-07-29 23:31:10.862924"
User.last.created_at_before_type_cast.class # => String
User.last.created_at # => Sat, 29 Jul 2017 23:31:10 UTC +00:00
User.last.created_at.class # => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
User.last.attributes_before_type_cast # => all attributes before type casting and such
```

I imagine this would work with your custom encrypted type

Answer (score 0):

As SimpleLime suggested...

```
namespace :encrypt do
  desc "Encrypt the unencrypted values in database"
  task encrypt_old_values: :environment do
    User.all.each do |user|
      if user.name.blank? && ! user.name_before_type_cast.blank?
        User.class_variable_get(:@@encrypted_fields).each do |att|
          user.assign_attributes att => user.attributes_before_type_cast[att.to_s]
        end
        user.save validate: false
      end
    end
```